# Permission error during startup of fast.ai course

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run the script `setup_p2.sh` for the fast.ai course. I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CreateVpc
>   operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.

NOTE: `setup_p2.sh` was NOT available at the stated location, but I found it by cloning this repo: https://github.com/fastai/courses

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution: Amazon changed the permissions screens when setting up the IAM (Identity Access Management) account. I solved it by creating a new security group with the "AdministratorAccess" permission, and adding that user to that group. Works now.